# How to create an .ipa file out of phonegap 3.5.0 project?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm very new to OS X and facing difficulties even in finding the menu options in xcode.

I tried all the resources available online. All I'm trying is to make an .ipa file out of the phonegap project which uses push notifications. I have tried phonegap build this way:

1. Created .p12 key and development provision file according to the instructions in the following link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

It's not working out. So, I started to use xcode to do it. But I don't find an option to edit scheme anywhere.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you device from iPhone/iPad in XCode to iOS Device then in the project build menu, select Archive. You will be prompted by Xcode to sign the app and if you don't have provisioning profile Xcode will assign you one.

Follow the archive menu to create an download the packaged IPA.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how to select the project build menu. Pardon me for my ignorance. I'm very new to OS X.

Comment: in XCode, click on "Project" then choose "Archive" from the menu. If there are no errors in your project, it will build and you will see a screen to choose if you are packaging it for App Store Delivery or Ad-Hoc inHouse use. Follow the prompts to save the ipa file on your desktop or computer.

Comment: make sure you are not set to simulate iphone or ipad...instead choose IOS Device next to your project before you build your archive.